# asihttprequest iOS 7,8 crash

Tags: ios

I'm using ASIHttpRequest to call web services through SOAP with xml format but on iphone 6 my app crash when I call ws many times consequential
Debugging I notice that error come on method "startSynchronous" of asihttp library

```
- (void)startSynchronous
{
    [self setSynchronous:YES];
    [self setRunLoopMode:ASIHTTPRequestRunLoopMode];
    [self setInProgress:YES];

    if (![self isCancelled] && ![self complete]) 
    {
        [self main];
        while (!complete)
        {
            NSLog(@"\n\n\n\nStack trace: %@\n\n\n\n", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
        ***[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:[self runLoopMode] beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];***

        }
    }
    [self setInProgress:NO];
}
```

can someone help me?
Exists another library like ASIHttpRequest for my goal? I found AFNetworking but I think it is only for JSON format, isn't it?

The stack trace is

Stack trace: (
    0   mobysign                            0x0019cd67 -[ASIHTTPRequest startSynchronous] + 346
    1   mobysign                            0x0008abc5 -[MainMenuViewController callWSGetMessageWithcipherString:] + 1764
    2   mobysign                            0x0008512f -[MainMenuViewController getMessages] + 1362
    3   mobysign                            0x00086def -[MainMenuViewController motionEnded:withEvent:] + 190
    4   UIKit                               0x25dd6b0f  + 894
    5   UIKit                               0x25dad15d  + 196
    6   UIKit                               0x26115abf  + 350
    7   BackBoardServices                   0x273b3e09 _BKXXDeliverAccelerometerEvent + 84
    8   BackBoardServices                   0x273b3121  + 60
    9   BackBoardServices                   0x273b338b  + 154
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x228b0573  + 34
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x228b050f  + 346
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x228aeb11  + 1608
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x227fc3c1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x227fc1d3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x29bb40a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
    16  UIKit                               0x25e0bfa1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
    17  mobysign                            0x00078a35 main + 116
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x30681aaf  + 2
)

Thank you in advance
Claudio

Comment: AFNetworking should be able to read XML too. But you says there is an error, which one? Any error message?

Comment: please, add the crash log...

Comment: Ok, You're right, I forgot it. The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS on row NSRunLoop currentRunLoop....but error happens only when I call ws many times repeatedly

Comment: @ClaudioDiPietra Author of asihttprequest itself accepted that the Networking framework is too big that he no longer able to provide updates or support so it is best to use AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I am fairly sure they stopped supporting ASIHTTP REQUEST like 3 years ago.